# Kotlin - Check to see if the generic parameter is optional or not?

Tags: android, generics, kotlin, nullable

I am writing this generic method to fetch data from firebase? In some cases getting null back is valid, in other cases is not, is it possible to check to see if the generic param is nullable or not?

ex

```
reference.obsrveObject(User.class)
```

should throw if null

```
reference.obsrveObject(User?.class)
```

should call onNext with null value

```
fun DatabaseReference.observeSingleEvent(): Observable<DataSnapshot?> {
    return Observable.create { subscriber ->
        val valueEventListener = object: ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot?) {
                subscriber.onNext(snapshot)
                subscriber.onCompleted()
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError?) {
                subscriber.onError(FirebaseDatabaseThrowable(error))
            }
        }

        addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener)
    }
}

fun <T>DatabaseReference.obsrveObject(clazz: Class<T>): Observable<T> {
    return observeSingleEvent().map { snapshot ->
        if (snapshot != null) {
            snapshot.getValue(clazz)
        }
        else {
            // if clazz is nullable return null
            // if clazz is not nullabel throw
            throw Exception("")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*Note: I've not personally used Firebase yet so some of the examples below may not compile but should be close enough.*

Neither [`Class<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) nor [`KClass<T>`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/) track nullability as they only represent a class. A [`KType`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-type/), however, can represent "a class with optional type arguments, plus nullability" and has an [`isMarkedNullable`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-type/is-marked-nullable.html) property.

You can use [reified type parameters](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters) to get a `KClass` for the generic type but you cannot get (as of Kotlin 1.1) a `KType`. However, you can still check to see if the generic type is nullable ([nullable reified type : Kotlin](https://www.reddit.com/r/Kotlin/comments/4g49nf/nullable_reified_type/)) with `null is T` (thanks to [sosite](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1973391/sosite) for [pointing out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45766885/kotlin-check-to-see-if-the-generic-parameter-is-optional-or-not/45775689#comment83112474_45775689) that wrapping `null as T` in a `try`/`catch` is not necessary).

---

With this, as long as you can mark `obsrveObject` as `inline`, you can "check to see if the generic parameter is optional or not":

```
inline fun <reified T> DatabaseReference.obsrveObject(): Observable<T> {
    return observeSingleEvent().map { snapshot ->
        if (snapshot != null) {
            snapshot.getValue(T::class.java)
        } else if (null is T) {
            null as T
        } else {
            throw Exception("")
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
databaseReference.obsrveObject<User>() // Observable<User>
databaseReference.obsrveObject<User?>() // Observable<User?>
```

---

If you cannot use an inline function (and therefore reified type parameters) then you need to find a way to get a `KType`.

You can get a `KType` from the `returnType` on `KCallable<R>` but you can also create a `KType` from a `KClass<T>` using [`createType`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.full/create-type.html):

```
User::class.createType(nullable = false)    // User
User::class.createType(nullable = true)     // User?
```

The class here is the type's [`classifier`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-type/classifier.html) so depending on how you are using `obsrveObject` you might change its argument type from `Class<T>` to `KCallable<T>`. You could change it to a `KType` directly and create instances as needed but I'm guessing your grabbing `clazz` currently from the return type of a property so I would go with `KCallable<T>`:

```
fun <T : Any> DatabaseReference.obsrveObject(callable: KCallable<T>): Observable<T?> {
    val kType = callable.returnType
    val kClass = kType.classifier as KClass<T>
    val clazz = kClass.java
    return observeSingleEvent().map { snapshot ->
        if (snapshot != null) {
            snapshot.getValue(clazz)
        } else if (kType.isMarkedNullable) {
            null
        } else {
            throw Exception("")
        }
    }
}
```

You would then call it using a reference to a callable (property, function, etc.):

```
databaseReference.obsrveObject(session::user)
```

Comment: Thanks, does the returned result have to be an observable of type optional?

Comment: Well if you want to be able to return `null` then you need to either return `Observable<T?>` or `Observable<T>?`. If you want the later then you should be able to `return null`.

Comment: I was hoping I would be able to define it as optional when needed, this is possible in swift, is it not in Kotlin? for example  Data<User>, Data<User?>, that way the generic type can be defined as optional or mandatory as user when needed

Comment: I think I better understand your use case now and I believe I've found a solution although it would be nice if Kotlin supported something like `T::type` in addition to `T::class` but there is a workaround. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is great, will try it

Comment: I think that much simpler solution to check if generic is nullable will be `inline fun <reified T> isMarkedNullable() = null is T`

Comment: Since Kotlin 1.6 you can get `KType` of reified type parameters using `typeOf<T>()`